# Labelling your stuff.  What's your method?

Tags: equipment, labels, management

I am making the transition into operating through an LLC of mine.  I have been slowly going through all the stuff I have and making an inventory and replacement cost for insurance.  With doing this I am realizing that most of my equipment is not labeled and I am not quite sure how to go about doing it.  Some of the cables that I have made, I use a label maker to put name on it then use clear heatshrink over to lock it in. But that option is not available on cables already done up without loping an end off and resoldering it.

What do you guys do for labeling things?.  I have a ton of mics that I use for live concerts and many times They are being used in conjunction with other companies microphones.  Anyone have a sleek professional looking way of labeling your stuff.  Right now I just have green Electric tape near the connectors on most of the Mics, but I have been thinking about maybe painting a small ring around them.  I do not want to engrave because It may damage the item.

Looking for a very clean and professional solution that way items can be wrangled by people other than myself.

Answer (score 1):

We use asset tags.

https://www.seareach.plc.uk/products/asset-labels/

If something is too small to take one, I will cut the tag down to fit, so that at least a portion is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use those battery powered label makers: http://www.brother-usa.com/Ptouch/

Good for all of your labeling needs: cables, connectors, equipment, filing systems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the production rental companies I work with either use sharpie or an engraving tool.  Not polished looking, but it is practical.

You could look into thermal printer labels, or if you want to be more secure, there are specific "inventory tag" labels either in plastic tape or metal-engraving that will be difficult to remove or leave an identifying mark behind if removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for what is called wire flag labels--when the heat shrink tube won't fit over the connector. Wire flag labels have a self laminating overwrap and work with curved surfaces. Most of the thermal transfer wire/cable label manufacturers have this - I use a K-Sun which has a variety label printers, some that work with your computer. The BEE3 that I use has the larger heat shrink tubes and is under $100.